# MVC Javascript pager datepicker C#

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, datepicker

I got a problem with paging, datepicker just work in startview, not after paging(dont pop up), got a plugin called mvc bootstrap pager. I got this in my view-bottom.

```
<div class="column full">
    @Html.Partial("_Pager")
</div>
<script>
    $(".column>.pagination>ul>li>a").on("click", function () {
        $("#browsePage").show();
    });
</script>
```

I also got a jquery datepicker in same view(higher up), but when i go to like page 2 it stopps working, i guess its some overriding in partial loading. How can i fix that? Inputs use ID now but it makes no difference with class.

```
<input class="datepicker search_filter" id="StartDate" 
type="text"     name="from_date" 
placeholder="From date"    value="@(ViewBag.fromDate)" />

<span><img src="~/Content/img/datepicker.png"       
class="datepicker3" />   </span>
                    <input class="datepicker search_filter" 
id="EndDate"  type="text" name="to_date" 
placeholder="To date"    value="@(ViewBag.toDate)" />
```

Comment: "I got a problem" don't use generic terms. please specify what is the problem ?

Comment: what goess wrong with Datepicker?

Comment: Doesnt show up in other pages, datepicker.